# I have an problem at hand on regular expressions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

`var pattern = /[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}/` 
This is the pattern, I have used to match the date string of format `Jan-12-2000`

Problem is I need the pattern for following strings,

- Jul 23, 2020
- Jul 23
- Jul 2020
- 23, 2020

I am really stuck at this trying so many options not getting exact result. Really appreciate if somebody could provide the solution.

Comment: You mentioned you've tried "*so many options not getting exact result*". Can you share  the attempts you've made? It'd be helpful to see so that the community may point out where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rgx = /([A-Z][a-z]{2,3}[-\s,])?\d{2,4}([-\s,]\d{4})?/;
console.log(rgx.test('Jan-12-2000'))
console.log(rgx.test('Jul 23, 2020'))
console.log(rgx.test('Jul 23'))
console.log(rgx.test('Jul 2020'))
console.log(rgx.test('23, 2020'))
```

Comment: This is matching `1234-1234` or `12` or `Feb 99`

Comment: @Toto Feb 99 is valid

Comment: Sure but not `Feb 99 1234`

Comment: @Toto Special for you: `/([A-Za-z]{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|([A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{2}(\d{2})?)|([A-Za-z]{3}\s\d{4})|(\d{2},\s\d{4})/`